# onItemClick setting text to the AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android

I have added a onTextChangedListener to my autocomplete textview and populate it using an async task

```
mAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        //run an async tast to get autocompletes
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});

private class getAutoCompletes extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //get autocompletes
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //create an adapter
        mAdapter AutoCompleteAdapter = new mAdapter(
                mActivity.this,
                R.layout.m_layout,
                R.id.m_id, autocompletesList);
        //set it to the autocomplete textview
        mAutoComplete.setAdapter(AutoCompleteAdapter);
        //show the dropdown
        mAutoComplete.showDropDown();
    }
}
```

Then I have `setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {}` on the mAutoComplete. But doing nothing in it.

**Still I get the String representation of the adapter as text in the mAutoComplete, when I click on any item in the dropdown**

```
com.xxxx.app.mAdapter@4342ca0
```

No where I am setting the text for the mAutoComplete.

**EDIT:**

**Adapter Class:**

```
public class mAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<customDS> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater = null;
    private Context ctx;
    public ArrayList<customDS> values = new ArrayList<customDS>();

    public mAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<customDS> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        values = objects;
        ctx = context;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return values.size();
    }

    public customDS getItem(int position) {
        return values.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView title;
        public TextView description;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.m_layout,
                    parent, false);
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.m_id);
            holder.description = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.m_id2);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.title.setText(values.get(position).title);
        holder.description.setText(values.get(position).description);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: How looks your customDS object? Add here its source code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Still I get the String representation of the adapter as text in the
>   mAutoComplete, when I click on any item in the dropdown

That's because when you select an item from drop down the auto complete widget will call the `toString()` method to fill the `EditText` where the input is inserted.

Try overriding the `toString()` method of the `customDS` class to return what you want to see there from the object.

Comment: I don't want to set any text, I want the text to be what was typed.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc Do you want the user to select an item but keep the text that was previously entered in the `EditText`? That would be very counter intuitive for the user in dealing with the **auto complete** widget.

Comment: The dropdown has different types of items. For a particular type of item if the user selects it, a popup comes in asking for **Proceed/Cancel** so on cancel I want the text to remain as it was previously(only what user typed).

Comment: @Archie.bpgc That also sounds very counter intuitive to the user(so you may want to let the user select what he/she wants and let it use a button to go further(asking for permission)). However there isn't anything stopping you from storing the text entered by the user in some variable(in the `TextWatcher`) and later using it to restore the widget to the initial state.

Comment: Is overriding the `toString()` method the only way to make it work? I use `toString()` methods of my POJOs for debugging purposes... And what if I've got two autocomplete fields in my application and want to return different fields of the POJO for each of them? That's disappointing...

Comment: @XtremeBiker Override the `convertSelectionToString()` method of the `AutoCompleteTextView` and return a `CharSequence` representing whatever part of the selected object you want. By default that method calls `toString()` on the selected item.

Comment: @Luksprog much better ;-) Probably an excellent added value for the answer.

Answer (score 20):

You can create a subclass of AutoCompleteTextView and override the "replaceText" method, as in it's superclass (AutoCompleteTextView) "replaceText" is used to replace the current text in the view when a result is clicked.

```
public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {
    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void replaceText(CharSequence text) {
        // do nothing so that the text stays the same
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks very hacky, but still could be a workaround, only if the `toString()` implementation for the current object contains what you really want to show up...

Comment: It is a bit, but aside from doing something completely custom, this seemed like a decent solution after reading through the AutoCompleteTextView source. Also I've been using this myself for a while and it seems to perform fine.

Comment: Look at other solution's comments. There's still a better solution.

Comment: Better solution is a bit subjective. I had seen the other solution before but wasn't a fan of it (saving and restoring text via the text watcher etc). Seeing as the replaceText functionality was essentially not needed for my use case, seemed fitting to simply make it do nothing. I think both ways are valid. Really only good argument against what I propose would be the changing of the API / parent class at some point.

Comment: Also I believe the AutoCompleteTextView relies on the toString of your object to be sane for it's purposes IIRC

Comment: The tostring method isn't something related with application's end client, IMO. If you take a look at the effective java book (Joshua Bloch) you'll find it's more related with documentation instead. Anyway, having to parse a String is much more unpleasant than overriding the convertSelectionToString method, which takes an object as a parameter and returns a String.

Comment: I don't really know what you're getting at with your statements, and I'm not gonna argue about it either, do whatever you like, though either solution could produce the end result desired depending on what you're looking for. good luck have fun.

Comment: @Override
    protected void replaceText(CharSequence text) {
        Editable currentText = getText();
        super.replaceText(currentText);
    }

Answer (score 5):

This is more simple. Try to add this in your activity. It works for me.

```
mAutoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        mAutoComplete.setText(((TextView) view).getText());

        // Or maybe you need to do something like this (it depends from your R.layout.m_layout):
        // LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) view;
        // TextView t = (TextView) l.getChildAt(0);
        // mAutoComplete.setText(t.getText());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to jaredpetker's solution:

```
@Override
    protected void replaceText(CharSequence text) {
        Editable currentText = getText();
        super.replaceText(currentText);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do .setText(""); in its onItemClick to avoid any set text on AutocompleteTextView. Below is the example:

```
  private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener =
        new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                query.setText("");
                UsersVO vo= (UsersVO)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                Intent intent=new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
                intent.putExtra("NAME",vo.getName());
                intent.putExtra("USER",vo.getUser());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
```

Where query is autoCompleteTextView.